# Promise Outside of Describe and It Blocks in Mocha.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

Can promise be run and fulfilled outside of `Describe` and `It` blocks in Mocha.js? 
I have following case:

```
login().then(function(spaces) {
    if (spaces.length > 1) {
        _.forEach(space, function() {
            describe(space.name, function() {
                it('test1');
                it('test2');
                it('test3');
            });
        });
    } else {
        describe(space.name, function() {
            it('test4');
        });
    }
});
```

But the tests don't seem to run. I tried to add `return` in front of login() as well since login is a promise. Still no luck. I would like to have my `space.name` listed out as `describe` name, but that name will be a result of login function...

Comment: What is login() and what `spaces` exactly are? You possibly have XY problem and don't need to do what you're trying to do. Any way, it's possible.

Comment: https://mochajs.org/#delayed-root-suite